# JavaScript Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2019

I was using Visual Studio Code to make a code, then when I  executed the code, this error appeared:
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined"

Heres the full code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const prefix = 'm!';
const fs = require('fs');

client.command = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, commad)
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is online!');
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'ping'){
        client.command.get('ping').execute(message, args);
    }
});
```

Comment: You have "client.commands" (with an "s") at one of the instances where you're trying to set a command.